# AD B2C integration with OKTA when OKTA is external IDP

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, okta, federated-identity, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

We have a requirement to integrate ADB2C with Okta as an external Identity Provider. There are 3 use cases I see:

1. Okta has users in the directory and those are users local to Okta.
2. Okta has users imported from the on-prem Active Directory and authenticated with AD credentials via Okta.
3. Okta has an Azure AD or other IDP configured as an external IDP (SAML or OIDC). To authenticate those users Okta /authorize url endpoint needs to be called and on each successful authentication an external IDP user becomes an JIT (just-in-time) Okta user, from what I've read in Okta docs.

I was able to set up B2C integration with Okta for #1 and #2 via B2C Custom policies. However, for the #3 I am wondering if it's even possible. And if yes than how. Because in this case Okta would be getting a token from an external IDP and then somehow forwarding that token to AD B2C and B2C would return it to the client. Has anyone had a similar experience/requirement?

Comment: 1/2/3 are all the same, federation with Okta. What Okta does is not really relevant as long as a token is issued from Okta to the relying party (in this case AAD B2C).

Comment: Thanks. Maybe there is something wrong with my setup, because I couldn't get #3 to work.

Comment: What exactly doesn’t work - detail the setup and observations in your post.

Comment: I followed the instructions here: https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/add-an-external-idp/openidconnect/use-idp-to-sign-in/ when setting up Azure AD as an external IDP to Okta. In the application registered in Azure AD the response redirect URI points to my Okta instance. In the application I registered in Okta (the one that B2C custom policies point to) I set up redirect URL as https://<my b2c domain>b2clogin.com/<my b2c domain>.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/authresp.

Comment: It works if I point the browser to Okta directly as described here https://developer.okta.com/docs/guides/add-an-external-idp/openidconnect/use-idp-to-sign-in/#html-link, however we need to see if our clients (potentially, because we don't know what their setup could be) could point the browser to B2C, from there to Okta and from Okta to an external Azure AD. That's why I was asking if it was even possible.

Comment: Sure, you can chain as much as you like.

Comment: Hi Marina, Were you able to configure OKTA as external IdP via SAML2 with custom policies?

Comment: I didn't use SAML. Okta now supports OIDC.

Answer (score 1):

Okta will not forward the token from it's external IDP to Azure B2C instead it will generate it's own token and pass it to Azure B2C.

If you need the actual token from Okta's external IDP, you will need to use the following API:
https://developer.okta.com/docs/reference/api/idps/#social-authentication-token-operation